Can't rollback an async session if error in db.commit()
When an error is thrown during await db.commit() call, I am not able to rollback the session due to MissingGreenlet spawn.
DB
async def get_db(self) -> AsyncIterator[AsyncSession]:
    session = self.scoped_session()
    try:
        yield session
    except Exception as e: # <- Instead of HTTPException, this is PendingRollbackError
        print("Rolling back the session") # <-- This is executed fine
        await session.rollback() # <- This will throw a MissingGreenLetError
        raise
    finally:
        await session.close()


Endpoint
async def do_something(db=Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        await db.commit() # raises IntegrityError due to UniqueConstraintViolation
    except IntegrityError as e:
        logger.error(f"Caught error {e}")
        raise HTTPException(400, "UniqueConstraintViolation")

What is odd that, IntegrityError is handled in do_something which raises HTTPException. But for some reason, instead of HTTPException, get_db catches PendingRollbackError.

Postgres logs
await db.commit() yields the following Postgres LOGS, which suggests that Postgres has ROLLBACKed:
 2024-09-24 12:44:58,391 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine UPDATE users_profiles SET username=$1::VARCHAR WHERE users_profiles.id = $2::VARCHAR

 2024-09-24 12:44:58,391 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00019s] ('xyz', '123')

 2024-09-24 12:44:58,579 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK

If I manually rollback my session, (or otherwise face PendingRollbackError) I get the MissingGreenlet spawn error:
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?


If I don't call .rollback(), then a PendingRollbackError is thrown.
The error log for PendingRollbackError is:
sqlalchemy.exc.PendingRollbackError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.IntegrityError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.UniqueViolationError'>: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(xyz) already exists.

And a Server Error 500.
What is going on?

Maybe try not using await on .rollback() because it's what's causing MissingGreenlet exceptions.

@ArlèmeJohnson Then it results in: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncSession.rollback' was never awaited. What is spooky is how HTTPException is replaced by PendingRollbackError. From my understanding IntegrityError invalidates the session, and it probably breaks asyncio logic

The issue was that HTTPException was invoking the greenlet spawn itself.
raise HTTPException(400, f"Username {DBobj.username} already taken")
